# Add a delay to progressbar.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, progress-bar

Working on an svg preloader, and i'd like a final path of the preloader to have a delay.  I'm using progressbar.js

so basically, if i have two paths, it would be

```
var bar_c2 = new ProgressBar.Path('#c2', {
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1000
});
bar_c2.set(0);
bar_c2.animate(1);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0

var bar_e2 = new ProgressBar.Path('#e2', {
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1000
});
bar_e2.set(0);
bar_e2.animate(1);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
```

I would like to have var bar_e2 begin after a delay of 900ms

any help in the right direction would be hugely appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i'm new to js and trying to learn, and i did!  I realized I could do this with a callback function, so i thought i would post here just so anyone else searching at my level would find the answer.

```
var bar_c2 = new ProgressBar.Path('#c2', {
});
var bar_e2 = new ProgressBar.Path('#e2',  {
});
path.set(0);
path.animate(1, {
    duration: 900
}, function() {
   line.animate(1);
});
```

It starts at the end of the first, which isn't exactly what i was going for, but good enough!